# Distinct Values in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have written xslt code to convert the xml code in the desired format. But the parent node is repeating every time after the child node. I want to display parent node once then its child nodes. Kindly let me know what can I do in the code to get the desired output.

Transform.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                 xmlns:app="http://www.eee.com/app">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="//*">
    <xsl:param name="prefix" />
    <xsl:param name="inLast" select="true()" />

<xsl:value-of select="$prefix"/>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat( local-name(), ' ', normalize-space())"/>
    <xsl:if test="not($inLast) or position() != last()">
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//*[*]">

    <xsl:param name="inLast" select="true()" />
    <xsl:variable name="num">
      <xsl:number />
    </xsl:variable>


    <xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="local-name()" />
      <xsl:with-param name="inLast" select="$inLast and position() = last()" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>


  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:LogDeliveryDocumentNotification xmlns:ns0="http://fmc.fmcworld.com/pi/MTD/LogDelivery">
<Employee1>
<Name>ABC</Name>
<Age>25</Age>
</Employee1>
<Employee2>
<Name>DEF</Name>
<Age>26</Age>
</Employee2>
</ns0:LogDeliveryDocumentNotification>
```

output:

```
Employee1
Name ABC
Employee1
Age 25
Employee2
Name DEF
Employee2
Age 26
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
Employee1
Name ABC
Age 25
Employee2
Name DEF
Age 26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no duplicate values in your input, so there is no need to extract distinct values. The result you're looking for can be produced easily by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">   
                <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**:
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYjg/2